# Maven: getting error on POM Non-resolvable parent

Tags: java, ios, macos, maven

I am running into an issue while trying to run an mvn command.this is what I am doing:

```
    enaxromac:ios enaxro$ mvn -f TTTTT/pom.xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.ios.xxxxxx:xxxx:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/enaxro/projects/xxxxx/main/xxxxxx/xxx/xxxxxxx/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.xxxxx.xxxxx.ios:root:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.xxxxx.maven.parent:legacy:pom:1.0.11 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ com.xxxx.xxxxxx.ios:root:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, /Users/enaxro/projects/xxxx/main/xxxxx/ios/pom.xml, line 3, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

My setup is the following:

```
enaxromac:ios enaxro$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 08:51:28-0500)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_37, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.7.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: Did you read the [help 2] page linked in the error, and checked those 6 possible causes?

Comment: Yeah no luck with that so far.

Comment: "mvn -f TTTTT/pom.xml". Try with absolute path of POM.

Comment: That did not solve it

Answer (score 2):

Check your settings.xml file. It should be in

```
<Userdir>/.m2
```

directory alongside the repository directory. This is one of the major reasons why we get the non-resolvable parent error. Also, for other possible solutions, check out this post:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/mavens-non-resolvable-parent

Answer (score 0):

Your parent Pom is being looked into the default maven repo.
You need to change your settings.xml and add the repo there.